# How to use Automated actions in Odoo 8?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I wanted to send emails a day(fewdays) before a particular due date.

I went on to try with automation actions and was confused with on how it would work

[image: Automated Actions]

and also the server action for that respective automated action

[image: Server Action]

I would like to know whether "based on timed condition" works or does not work, as far as I have tried and researched, this seems to be a bug or which does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Automated Actions do work, and are quite useful.

One catch with timed conditions is that they are triggered once and only once for each document/record, when the time condition is reached for the first time.

If you are playing around with timed conditions and use the same document/record for your tests, it will seem that later tries don't work, since triggered once it won't be triggered again.

In this scenario, you need to test changes to the Automated Action using a different test record.

Other things that might be wrong:

- Your outgoing email might not be working properly.
- The filter in your Automated Action might not be correct. Make sure you test it on a list view, and that the "User" field is blank.